# How can I add Selenium to Excel VBA 2013?

Tags: vba, excel, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to develop an Excel VBA project that interacts with the browser. I hear Selenium is a great tool for this but Excel 2013 where I work doesn't seem to have it listed as an object library under Tools > References... in the VBA editor.

Is there a site where I can download Selenium for Excel VBA and import it via the Browse button, or am I doomed to abandon this project? Having looked online, I can find selenium downloads for several programming languages, but not VBA.

Alternately, is there some other method I can use to read the URL of a user's active tab in a Chrome browser with Excel? The computers here are pretty locked down so I can't write a chrome extension for them like I usually would so I'm looking for a workaround!

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm using selenium for a while now to get some data from sites opened in Chrome. Here is the excel add-in site: [Selenium excel add-in](https://seleniumexceladdin.codeplex.com/). In the download page you can find samples as well.

Comment: Thank you Dawid, but this is an exe file. It cannot be imported as a library into excel and appears to need to be run via installshield, but the computers here won't let me install it so I'm still looking for an .olb, .tlb or .tll file to add Selenium as a reference library to Excel.

Comment: Have you tried to see if these work? https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic, http://htejera.users.sourceforge.net/vbswebdriver/

Answer (score 3):

you can install add in and then enable Selenium wrapper option in Excel>Tools>reference and then you can proceed with your activities.
Visit [Selenium Add in for excel](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0) to download the file

Comment: This link downloads an installer which is an .EXE file. The web drivers seem OK but it tries to install an IDE for Firefox which fails because it is "corrupt".

Comment: This works for Excel 365 VBA. Option Explicit

//Public Sub sbSeleniumTutorial()
 //MsgBox "sbSeleniumTutorial()"
 //Dim bot As New WebDriver
 //bot.Start "edge", "https://www.yahoo.com"
 //bot.Get "/"
//End Sub