# Selenium VBA Excel stop browser closing

Tags: vba, selenium, browser

hi guys i need help with my vba code, i just want the code to finish and leave the window open

```
Sub BCAuto()

Dim obj As New WebDriver
obj.Start "Chrome", "https://www.google.com"
obj.Get "https://www.google.com"
obj.Window.Maximize

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have the selenium excel add-in installed? You need to install the add-in and add the reference library. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479711/how-can-i-add-selenium-to-excel-vba-2013)

Comment: And what isn't working? Your code as written should do that if set-up correct.

Comment: having the same problem here with the same code. The browser closes. I think dwirony wants it to stay open and pass control to the OS.